# How to remove characters in str2 when there is a match for a character from str1?

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

I have tried to remove the characters in str2 when there is a match for a character from str1.Suppose if the string2 is "Haelloi Waoruld" and string1 is "aiu" then after removing the each character from string 1 in strin2 , the string2 looks like : "Hello World"

Though I could solve this with normal string operations, I was asked to implement the same using hash table concept from C language . I have no idea how to implement this in hash table.

Can anyone help me with the algorithm for the same ?

Comment: I would suggest: A) Showing what you have so far, B) Tagging your question with the language you are using, and C) start accepting answers that people have given you in the past. This is a trivial exercise. Why make it hard?

Comment: Why use a hash table? It sounds like the wrong data structure. A table, maybe, but a hash table?! Is that homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go over str1, create a boolean table indexed by character with true if the character is in str1. Then go over str2 and output only characters for which the value in the table is false.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you share me some sample algorithm or any link within this forum where there is a similar type of implementation. I have never implemented a hash table before :-(